# TypeScript - Which files should I check in?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, typescript

If I add a TypeScript file in Visual Studio 2013, for instance Index.ts, I will also get an Index.js and a Index.js.map file. The js-file is a compiled version of the ts-file so my question is if the js-file should be version controlled aswell or? In other words, should I check it in to the TFS? Because in a sense the js-file becomes a binary when working with TypeScript.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is best to treat the JavaScript like a binary - don't check in the `js` or `map` files at all.

This avoid noise in your source control repository and also means the build process doesn't need to overwrite source-controlled `js` files, which is a problem in some situations.

Comment: We use a build server here so if we don't check in our generated js files we need to rebuild them on the build server.

Comment: If you delete a .ts file from TFS, isn't everyone else left with stray .js and .map files in their local project?

Comment: Except if the .js file will be an embedded resource. Then the .js has to be included into the project and thus is under source control.

Comment: @Hefaistos68 typically, I would generate a package on the build server (i.e. like an NPM package, or even plain built artefacts places somewhere to be used) and this _would_ contain the `.js` and the `.map` files - but the ones created as part of the build; not the ones from a developer's own machine.